# Problema al mostrar atributos definidos en el onMapReady (sólo en algunos dispositivos)

Tags: java, android, google-maps

Tengo una aplicación que ejecuta un mapa, polylines y marcadores; el problema que tengo es que al ejecutar la aplicación en 3 teléfonos, en 2 se muestra todo correctamente y en el tercero no se muestran los atributos definidos en el onMapReady. ¿Por qué puede ocurrir eso?

Dejo a continuación el código de la clase:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener, OnMapReadyCallback {

    GoogleMap map;
    GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    String email;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();
        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

        FirebaseUser user= FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        //obtener datos para la barra
        if(user != null) {

            String nombre=user.getDisplayName();
            email=user.getEmail();
            Uri foto=user.getPhotoUrl();

            NavigationView navigationsView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
            View hView =  navigationsView.getHeaderView(0);
            TextView nav_user = (TextView)hView.findViewById(R.id.txtMail);
            TextView name=(TextView) hView.findViewById(R.id.txtNombre);
            ImageView img_user = (ImageView)hView.findViewById(R.id.profile_image);

            name.setText(nombre);
            nav_user.setText(email);
            Picasso.with(this).load(foto).into(img_user);
        }
        else {
            SharedPreferences loginbdd=getSharedPreferences("login", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            email=loginbdd.getString("nombre","");
            String nombre=loginbdd.getString("mail","");

            NavigationView navigationsView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
            View hView =  navigationsView.getHeaderView(0);
            TextView nav_user = (TextView)hView.findViewById(R.id.txtMail);
            TextView name=(TextView) hView.findViewById(R.id.txtNombre);
            ImageView img_user = (ImageView)hView.findViewById(R.id.profile_image);

            nav_user.setText(email);
            name.setText(nombre);
        }

    }

    private void goLogin() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Login.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this)
                    .setIcon(R.drawable.cerrar).setTitle("Cerrar Aplicación").setMessage("Deseas cerrar CicloMapp?")
                    .setCancelable(true).setPositiveButton("Si", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            System.exit(0);
                        }

                    })
                    .setNegativeButton("No", null).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        } else if (id == R.id.endSession) {
            new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this)
                    .setIcon(R.drawable.cerrar)
                    .setTitle("Cerrar sessión")
                    .setMessage("Deseas cerrar sesión?")
                    .setCancelable(true)
                    .setPositiveButton("Si", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            FirebaseUser user=FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
                            if(user!= null){
                                LoginManager.getInstance().logOut();
                                FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
                                goLogin();
                            }else{
                                SharedPreferences loginbdd=getSharedPreferences("login", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                                SharedPreferences.Editor editor=loginbdd.edit();
                                editor.remove("inicio");
                                editor.commit();
                                goLogin();
                            }
                        }

                    })
                    .setNegativeButton("No", null).show();
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.AgregarRuta) {

        } else if (id == R.id.ValorarRuta) {
            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Valoraraciones.class);
            i.putExtra("correo", email);
            startActivity(i);
        } else if (id == R.id.ReportarRuta) {
            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Reportar.class);
            i.putExtra("correos", email);
            startActivity(i);
        } else if (id == R.id.Eventos) {

        } else if (id == R.id.Refresco) {

        } else if (id == R.id.Leyes) {

        }
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(final GoogleMap googleMap) {
        map=googleMap;
        map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
                ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            return;
        }
        map.getUiSettings().setMapToolbarEnabled(false);
        map.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);
        map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        map.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
        CameraUpdate center = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(new LatLng(-33.447487,-70.673676));
        CameraUpdate zoom = CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(11);
        map.moveCamera(center);
        map.animateCamera(zoom);
        Polyline po = new Polyline();
        po.AddPolyline(map);

        int height = 50;
        int width = 50;
        BitmapDrawable bitmapdraw = (BitmapDrawable) getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.mruta);
        Bitmap b = bitmapdraw.getBitmap();

        Bitmap smallMarker = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(b, width, height, false);
        final Marcadores ma=new Marcadores();
        ma.MarcadoreBdd(map,smallMarker);

    }

}
```

este es mi gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    signingConfigs {
        Firma {
            keyAlias 'androiddebugkey'
            keyPassword 'android'
            storeFile file('C:/Users/Javier/.android/debug.keystore')
            storePassword 'android'
        }
    }
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.ciclomapp.ciclomapp.ciclomapp"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        signingConfig signingConfigs.Firma
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        debug {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.Firma
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
        compile project(':jtds-1.3.1')
        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.8.0'
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.8.0'
        compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.1'
        compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.2.1'
        compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)'
        testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.8.0'
        compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.0.2'
        compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.0.2'
        compile "com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.4.0"
        compile 'com.github.SubhrajyotiSen:library:1.1.1'
        compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0'
        compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
}
apply plugin:'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

y este es el manifest

```
?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.ciclomapp.ciclomapp.ciclomapp">

    <!-- To auto-complete the email text field in the login form with the user's emails -->

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />

    <application
        android:name=".Facebook"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/logo"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyB8GlerfcCyBJo_Lcz1EJ4iT0YTsrlpM38" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
            android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/>

        <activity
            android:name=".Inicio"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Login"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value=".Inicio" />
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".Registrarse" />
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity android:name=".Valoraraciones" />
        <activity android:name=".Reportar"></activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Hola Zhet a que atributos te refieres?

Comment: el problema es que en el tercer telefono el metodo onMapReady, no se ejecuta, pero en los otros 2, se ejecuta perfectamente

Comment: Podría ser un problema de soporte/compatibilidad ¿Son los 3 el mismo modelo de teléfono?¿Tienen la misma versión de OS?

Comment: no, los primeros 2 funcionan con api 4.4(19) y el tercero funciona con api 6.0(23) marshmallow

Comment: ¿Qué versión de la API de Google Maps estás usando? Porque por lo que dices, casi te diría que es una incompatibilidad de algún tipo

Comment: te refieres a la version de google services? si es asi 9.8.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android 6.0 (Marshmallow) presenta un nuevo modelo para administrar permisos

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
    if (requestCode == MY_LOCATION_REQUEST_CODE) {
    if (permissions.length == 1 &&
          permissions[0] == Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION &&
        grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
     mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    } else {
    // Permission was denied. Display an error message.
    }
}
```

Saludos.

Comment: podrias entregarme documentacion acerca del tema porfavor?, digo para no hacer preguntas futuras acerca de lo mismo :),

Comment: Si claro checa la liga en : https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

Comment: gracias  amigo :)

Comment: De nada !. Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Veo que tienes correctamente implementado correctamente tu código para que se ejecute el llamado de `onMapReady()` :

```
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);    
mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
```

Para **Android 6.0 o mayor implementa requerir los permisos**:

```
   int permissionCheck = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
    if (permissionCheck != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        Log.i(TAG, "No se tiene permiso ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION. Requiriendo permisos.");
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, 225);
    } else {
        Log.i(TAG, "Se tiene permiso!");
    }
```

Para que esto funcione obviamente tiene que agregar en tu AndroidManifest.xml el permiso:

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Revisa la documentación:
**https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html**

**https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/location**

Comment: es un galaxy s7 edge el que me da el problema, por ende no creo que sea problema de hardware

Comment: listo, comparti ambos :)

Comment: deberia meter el codigo del dentro del if? o como implemento ese if?

Comment: Al iniciar tu aplicacion valida solo para OS 6 y posterior.

Comment: si, pero mi pregunta es, donde colocalo la condicion, en el oncreate o en el onmapready y si falta colocarle algo a la sentencia positiva

Comment: @zhet agregue como debes requerir el permiso, llamalo en tu MainActivity al iniciar tu aplicación o antes de llamar el mapa, con esto funcionaría correctamente tu aplicación, saludos!.

Comment: muchas gracias :)